# The type junit.framework.TestCase cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, jmock, junit3

I'm following the example here: [jMock - getting started](http://www.jmock.org/getting-started.html)

I'm getting this error: The type junit.framework.TestCase cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I've imported these 4 jars:

- jmock-2.5.1.jar
- hamcrest-core-1.1.jar
- hamcrest-library-1.1.jar
- jmock-junit3-2.5.1.jar

Ant ideas of what this error means?

```
package com.test;

import org.jmock.integration.junit3.MockObjectTestCase;
import org.jmock.Expectations;

class PublisherTest extends MockObjectTestCase {
public void testOneSubscriberReceivesAMessage() {
    // set up
    final Subscriber subscriber = mock(Subscriber.class);

    Publisher publisher = new Publisher();
    publisher.add(subscriber);

    final String message = "message";

    // expectations
    checking(new Expectations() {
        {
            oneOf(subscriber).receive(message);
        }
    });

    // execute
    publisher.publish(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not have the jUnit3.8.1 jar in my classpath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add JUnit 3 to your classpath.